# CSS strange behavior with fading gradient from left to right and right to left

Tags: html, css

I need your help. I've developed this little code to make my image (here it's a green background) fade to white at the beginning and the end. Somehow on any mobile device this gradient looks really strange with a dark center:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: wheat;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
      flex-direction: row;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    place-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#wrap::after,
#wrap::before {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 6rem;
    z-index: 1;
}

#wrap::before {
    background: linear-gradient(90deg,#fff,hsla(0,0%,100%,.7) 50%,transparent);
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#wrap::after {
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg,#fff,hsla(0,0%,100%,.7) 50%,transparent);
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
  
</div>
```

This is how it looks on mac with chrome:

[image]

The same code on my phone:

[image]

Thats how I should looks like in the end:

[image]

Comment: And what do you expect to be?

Comment: maybe it's the hsla() ?

Comment: It should be the same on the phone like above without this gray something strange nearly at the center

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a different idea, maybe it will behave correctly

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to left ,wheat calc(100% - 6rem) , transparent) left,
    linear-gradient(to right,wheat calc(100% - 6rem) , transparent) right;
  background-size:51% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

</div>
```

**UPDATE**

Using mask:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  -webkit-mask: 
    linear-gradient(to left ,#fff calc(100% - 6rem) , transparent) left,
    linear-gradient(to right,#fff calc(100% - 6rem) , transparent) right;
  -webkit-mask-size:51% 100%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat:no-repeat;
  background:wheat;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

</div>
```

Or an extra layer:

```css
#wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  background:wheat;
  flex-direction: row;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position:relative;
}
#wrap::before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background: 
    linear-gradient(to left ,transparent calc(100% - 6rem) , #fff) left,
    linear-gradient(to right,transparent calc(100% - 6rem) , #fff) right;
  background-size:51% 100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrap">

</div>
```

Comment: Seems to be a bit problematic because my wrap has some childs aka logos and they're not visible now anymore. Do you have another idea that my logos are still visible?

Comment: @Mr.Jo my code should not affect the visibility of anything. I am simply applying a background. Maybe you didn't copy the code correctly? or did you remove something else without paying attention?

Comment: Ah the logos are in front of the background so they are not fading into the white. Thats why I was unable to see the problem. I'll update my question with an image that shows the desired result - sorry.

Comment: @Mr.Jo added another code, you will need mask in such situation

Comment: @Mr.Jo or one extra layer (added a 3rd code)

Comment: I like the last one and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot Temani :)